# define the default value of an ansible list as a dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using the code shown in the attached picture: [Code used for my loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WcJr.png)

I need that each iteration starts the count from `0`, and not from `1`. I mean specifically the following line:

```
tmp_list: "{{ tmp_list | default([]) + [dict(name=item.key,seq=lookup('sequence','count='+item.value|string,wantlist=true))] }}"
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you are asking for.

If you are just looking to get the number of the current loop iteration + 1 you can do that with something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- name: Lets do some loops
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_list:
    - one
    - two
    - three
  tasks:
  - name: Loop plus one
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} {{ loop_index + 1 }}"
    loop: "{{ my_list }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: loop_index



PLAY [Lets do some loops] ********************************************************************************************

TASK [Loop plus one] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=one) => {
    "msg": "one 1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=two) => {
    "msg": "two 2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=three) => {
    "msg": "three 3"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

You can find more information in the [Loop Control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) section in the official Ansible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
- set_fact:
    tmp_list: "{{ tmp_list | default([]) + [dict(name=item.key,seq=lookup('sequence','start=0 count='+item.value|string,wantlist=true))] }}"
    with_dict: "{{ objs }}"
```